# Allowed memory size exhausted error < how to reset?

Tags: php, memory

I have been running a loop where I inserted 50,000 data sets into a MySQL database. Suddenly the server on my hosted space shows this message:

> **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 20971520 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /srv/www/htdocs/server/html/email.php on line
>   14**

I know what it means, but how can I reset all the memory so it can be used again?

Note:

I do not want to increase my memory, like with

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

but want to completely release it.

Comment: The odds are your script can be rewritten to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks John. I know, I have already done this. But how can I release the memory that now seems to be blocked?

Comment: That depends on your code ...

Comment: Are u putting the query in all at once? can't you split the 50k datasets in small insert packs? maybe post parts of your code here

Comment: Do you mean there is no php command / function to release the memory? I actually get this error from calling other scripts as well, not the one that caused the problem!

Comment: You can use `unset()` which _may_ release some memory. Also if you're on 5.3 or above, `gc_collect_cycles()` may be of use.

Comment: Is this PHP you're running inside a web server, or on the command line?

Comment: (It sounds like this is happening _between_ executions. If so, you may need to talk to your host - your script may be cached via your opcode accelerator).

Comment: It's on a hosted web server where I upload my scripts via FTP, so I cannot restart the machine myself. Maybe I have to wait because it will have to restart eventuall right?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I cannot access all the variables that have been set. It happens on a different script when trying to use PDO > fetchAll to get the MySQL results.

Comment: Using PDO fetchAll is not a good idea if there are thousands of results... it uses lots and lots of memory... wonder if there's a connection

Answer (score 1):

When you have a shared system from a Provider in most cases you cannot set the memory limit for yourself. Then when every 100 People on the Server set a higher memory limit the provider has a problem.

So they give a fixed size in your case 20MB and disable the **memory_limit** function.

20MB is not so much. And when you try to insert a lot of datasets you need some memory. This is the reason why there comes the message **32 bytes** from allowed memory **20971520 bytes**.

I think with 20MB there is no real good solution to solve this problem. Perhaps you can try to put some logic to the database and make a **stored procedures**.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Stony. Do you happen to know how I can reset the memory? It seems as though the variables are still filled with information from a query I did 2 days ago. Funnily, the ini_set function works, even though my provider sells memory increases separately.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have seen this question again. And perhaps you should add your code here. Perhaps we can optimize this code. Or is this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found it so I think it's worth posting for others.

I came across this error whilst trying to carry out a bulk system update to a single field in every record. 
The records were read into an array, processed and updated back to the database.
I believe the error was caused by too much data stored in the array on the server.

To get over the problem, I split the task up to handle 1000 records at a time.
i.e; (Code Tested.

```
$r_count=1; $start_id=0; $end_id=1000;
while($r_count>0)
{ 
 $strSQL="SELECT * from spAddbook 
           WHERE id > '$start_id' AND id <= '$end_id'"; 
 $result = mysql_query($strSQL, $link) or die ("Couldn't read because ".mysql_error());
 $r_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo"<br>$r_count found<br>";
 if (mysql_num_rows($result))
 {
  while ($qry = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   // Read the Data and carry out processing
  }    
 }
 $start_id+=1000; $end_id+=1000;
} 
echo"<br><br>All Done";
```

I Hope this helps.. It worked for me.